# Android error while changing sdk in the middle of project

Tags: android, apache, android-studio

Story:

I am trying to build a basic user authentication android app. First I was using my target SDK as 23 but then I came to know that all the apache libraries are removed from the current android sdk release.

Since I've my project deadline coming on, I want to stick to API 22 as many resources and tutorials are available for the apache libraries.

What I did:

I changed the project structure as you can see in the attachment.

[image: Press F4]

Error:

In all the java files the following error is thrown:

```
Cannot resolve the symbol R
```

Comment: Clean project and build again.

Comment: @AlekseyMazurov It's still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I just saw that Google suggest's using [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead of using Apache because HttpUrlConnection is more efficient than Apache's library.

Maybe you consider rewrite your code to match Google suggestions if this isn't that much effort before your deadline

Answer (score 1):

Is suppose you change your target API version back to 23 and import all the apache library by yourself into your project:

Just add the following line into your build.gradle file under the android collection:

```
android {
   ...
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
   ...
}
```

Comment: You should have somewhere in your 'project folder', I think under the folder 'app' an file 'build.gradle' and there are all your dependencies listed in curly brackets like this `dependencies {compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'}` and there add the upper lines

Comment: If you don't have this file it could be that your editor uses another build tool than "Gradle". Then try to add the dependencies using the UI as I described in the EDIT

Comment: It's still throwing the same error. Earlier with this configuration it wasn't throwing any error but now it is.